# Summing and normalizing pandas dataframe based on other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given this dataframe:

```
    HOUSEID   PERSONID  HHSTATE  TRPMILES
0   20000017    1         IN    22.000000
1   20000017    1         IN    0.222222
2   20000017    1         IN    22.000000
3   20000017    2         IN    22.000000
4   20000017    2         IN    0.222222
5   20000017    2         IN    0.222222
6   20000231    1         TX    3.000000
7   20000231    1         TX    2.000000
8   20000231    1         TX    6.000000
9   20000231    1         TX    5.000000
```

I want to sum values in `TRPMILES` based on unique combination of `HOUSEID` and `PERSONID`:

```
     HOUSEID   PERSONID  HHSTATE  TRPMILES
0   20000017    1         IN    66.666666
1   20000017    2         IN    22.444444
2   20000231    1         TX    16.000000
```

then normalize the `TRPMILES` based on `HHSTATE`. I mean dividing every number of the same `HHSTATE` category by the maximum number of trip mile in `HHSTATE` column.

(66.666666 is maximum for `IN` so dividing it by itself is 1.0000000 and by the second row is 0.3366666)

```
  HOUSEID   PERSONID  HHSTATE  TRPMILES
0   20000017    1         IN    1.0000000
1   20000017    2         IN    0.3366666
2   20000231    1         TX    1.0000000
```

I have a big dataframe with many possible values of `HHSTATE`.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your own attempt using `groupby` please. Hint - do a groupby with `sum` to get your intermediate table and then a groupby with `transform(max)` on that intermediate table to a column of the max's you want to divide by.

Comment: Or any attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `groupby` then do `div`

```
s=df.groupby(['HOUSEID',  'PERSONID', 'HHSTATE'])['TRPMILES'].sum()
s=s.div(s.max(level=[2]),level=2).reset_index()
```